# Display an array as a sentence in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I need to reverse an array created by user input. I've got everything working however I would like the sentenced to be simply reversed rather than reversed and shown as individual words. I've got this so far but thinking I might have to approach this problem entirely differently.

```
        //Prompt user for sentence
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a sentence with at least 5 words:");
        string userSentence = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] sentenceArray = userSentence.Split(' ');

        Array.Reverse(sentenceArray);


        foreach (string word in sentenceArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, input : "I am good" -> ouput: "doog ma I" ? Correct?

Comment: You are almost there. Use string.Join: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx and you are golden :)

Comment: `string userSentence = "abc def ghj";
            
            foreach (char letter in userSentence.Reverse())  Console.Write(letter);`

Comment: Can you add a sample input and the expected output to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of the for loop, use string.Join() to combine all elements of the array into a single string.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", sentenceArray));
```

Comment: Whenever you can replace a loop with a one liner a rainbow is born.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you want to split the string first, but, you can inverse the split array like this:

```
var s = "I am good";
string[] sentenceArray = s.Split(' ');
var a =  string.Join(" ", sentenceArray).ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(a);
var ss = new string(a);
Console.WriteLine(a); //doog ma I
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to split the string. Just convert it into an array, reverse it convert it back to string.

```
public static void Main()
{
    //Prompt user for sentence
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a sentence with at least 5 words:");
    string userSentence = Console.ReadLine();
    string reversed = Reverse(userSentence);
    Console.WriteLine(reversed);
}

public static string Reverse(string data)
{
    char[] dataArray = data.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(dataArray);
    return new string (dataArray);
}
```